# returning promise to a variable without $$state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have the following promise

```
let oembedData = oembed(uuid)
    .then(res => res);

console.log(oembedData);
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to return the `res` to `oembedData` so the value can be used.

I know I can do

```
let oembedData;
oembed(uuid)
    .then((res) => {
        oembedData = res;
        console.log(oembedData);
    });
```

but I feel this way isn't as clean as the former example.

When I use the former my console log returns `Promise {$$state: {…}}`

Comment: Your two examples aren't equivalent. `console.log` should just be inside the `.then` callback doing `console.log(res);` so you don't need `oembedData` at all.

Comment: Did your function returning a deffered varibable ?

Comment: You don't do that. You do your thing inside the `.then(function(){/* here */}`. Promises are Asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're free to use `async/await`, it looks almost like you'd want.

```
async function oembed(uuid) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 3000));
}

async function getOembed() {
  try {
      const oembedData = await oembed('1234');
      console.log(oembedData);
  } catch(err) {
      handleError(err);
  }
}

getOembed();
```

Comment: I still need to use `getOembed().then()` here done i?

Comment: No, you can wrap await oembed in a try/catch block instead of then...catch

Comment: updated example